# Difference smart card with same ATR

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard

In a Java program I need to difference two identical Javacard and GlobalPlatform smart cards (with same ATR, of course). I need do it before to establish any secure channel, so is there a way to know the aid's of the applets that there are installed in the card without use the GET STATUS command? Can I change the historical bytes of the ATR of one card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out the possible AID's using the SELECT by NAME APDU. Otherwise, no, you cannot request the applet AID's without authenticating to the card manager.

Note that you may shorten the AID to 5 bytes (the RID), the card manager should select an applet with an instance AID that starts with the same RID.

Comment: Simple and effective, great answer, it works fine!!